# Project wide emoji search

Tags: visual-studio-code, emoji

I have a project with more than a thousand emojis spread around all files.
I would like to remove them.
To achieve this, I would really appreciate to be able to search for them.

Do you guys know a good way to search for emojis ?
Maybe with a regex ?

Thanks

Comment: construct a character class with a Unicode range `[a-z]`